# Cloudformation AWS::ApiGateway::ClientCertificate expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

The client certificate in the API Gateway to connect to the application servers expired. The client certificate was created with a cloud CloudFormation Template and wired to the resources. 
The [official Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html#certificate-rotation) just tells how to do this via Web Console, but not how to update via CloudFormation.

Executing a Change Set won't help because it's an unchanged Template.

**How to rotate a Client Certificate deployed by CF?**

CF-Part to create the Client Certificate:

```
Api1ClientCertificate:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::ClientCertificate"
  Properties:
    Description: !Sub "Client Certificate for environment ${Environment}"
```

Question on AWS Forum about client certificate, but with no helpful answers
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246662

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'd need to effectively change the template to something like:

```
Api1NewClientCertificate:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::ClientCertificate"
    Properties:
        Description: !Sub "Client Certificate for environment ${Environment}"
```

And then replace all references to Api1ClientCertificate with Api1NewClientCertificate and update the stack.